Is it okay to make some jokes with the client in daily scrum calls?
I work with a client and report to them during our scrum calls or daily updates. Initially, as the new team member, I limited my updates strictly to work-related matters.
However, I observed that the client often made small jokes and engaged in light-hearted interactions. I realized that to foster better critical thinking and create an environment where ideas can flow freely, I too began making small jokes that would make people laugh. I always ensure that I don’t cross any boundaries.
In my experience with two clients from the same company, Company A, their approaches differed. One was very funny, casual, and had a friendly attitude. The current client, while pretending to be friendly, seems stricter and carries a bit more ego. However, the current client too makes up some small jokes occasionally.
I’m curious about whether it’s appropriate to continue making jokes now and then, considering this client is external to my company (Company B). Could it potentially harm my company if the client prefers a more serious approach?

Why exactly is your client in a Daily Scrum? Which of the Scrum Roles do they fit in? What is their function in those meetings? Is it for their benefit, or yours? Who required them to be there?

He is the tech lead from his company's side (20+ yoe). He has 2 teams under him

But why is he in your Daily Scrum? What is his role there, what does he contribute, why is he there?

Don't know. But, in all the projects that I have worked so far, client is the scrum master

It is one thing for the several minutes prior to meeting start. Once that meeting starts, then it is another - strictly business.

Humor is done best when the object is myself, never the client, never a subordinate.

If you have to ask, the answer is "no". When you are comfortable reading the room, you'll no longer need to ask.

@nvoigt: I think you're conflating a customer (someone who buys your product) with a contractor's client (someone who buys your labor for their product). OP is a contractor whose client (i.e. who OP bills their hours to) is the company who owns the codebase, i.e. the company who OP performs the work for.

@DogBoy37: I'm apprehensive of the kind of blanket statements you're writing down here. Acting strictly business with someone whose attitude is informal/collegial is can just as negatively impact OP.

@Flater I understand that. You make it seem obvious that such an individual should be in the Daily scrum meeting. Looking into the scrum guide, it does not mention a "client". In what capacity is this client in the Scrum meeting? What role do they fill? There is a difference between someone organically in a meeting and someone who is forced to be in a meeting. One might see jokes as good for the team they are part of, the other as a total waste of their precious time. Or maybe they just labelled it "Daily Scrum" without doing actual Scrum, in which case my assumptions would be all wrong.

@Flater Please don't read into any of my comments as a blanket statement. However that is a good example of something that I try to teach my employees, assume everything that you write will be taken the wrong way. Back to the point of OP's question, my suggestion is based on the idea to always be a just slightly more "Up Tight" than the client. Not much, just a little. This has worked well for my company.

@DogBoy37 "slightly more uptight" is relative. "Strictly business" is an absolute.

@DogBoy37 Yes. My jokes are very limited. I try to be professional. Being an office clown is not my thing

@pc_fuel It sounds like we are all on the same page. Keep the client comfortable, follow their lead. Keep it professional.

You follow where they lead and exercise a bit of Judgement
So, I banter a lot with Clients. More than my team mates, and that is fine, I am a Native Brit - so Banter is in my blood. Usually the jokes I make are a combination of self-deprecating, poking fun at my company and semi-work related:

trying to avoid work, but my boss keeps giving me things to do
suggesting to a client that they reset my account to $0 for their app that I use
Why Microsoft Teams is an abomination
trying to get my Company to fly me up to the major city, to meet face-to-face with the clients and put me up in a hotel for a week.

etc.
All light-hearted, nothing serious - I usually reserve these for the start of the meeting (whilst we are waiting for everyone to join) and then when it is time for business, its 90 percent business (sometimes there is a really good opportunity for a Pun or a good witticism related to the current topic we are discussing)
I find it helps lighten the mood and helps the meeting go smoothly.
If the client engages in the Banter or otherwise cracks a joke, then that is the greenlight that they are okay with a little bit of light-heartedness.
However, knowing a time and place is also critical - we had an issue where a customer experienced major downtime and we had a follow-up meeting after the issue - there were no jokes made in that meeting, especially after the Dollar figure of lost revenue was shared.
In short - if you know two people at the same company have different levels of friendliness, you taylor your delivery to each person. The person that is mostly serious but cracks the odd joke - reciprocate in kind, be mostly business but when there is a good opportunity, make a slight witticism. If you know that you have a particularly serious meeting or subject - dial it back completely.
Whereas with the other person who likes a bit more back-and-forth, make sure engage at a level that is appropriate.
In terms of hurting your company reputation - so long as you steer away from humor that is likely to offend (Sex, Politics, Religion etc.) - I would say no, especially if they open the door (so-to-speak).
In fact, it can even strengthen the relationship with the client - the above mentioned client with the outage - before I was assigned to the account, the business relationship was a bit strained. Whilst one of the key factors in turning the relationship around was the actual work being done, I like to think that doing it with a smile and a quip made sure that the client enjoyed working with us - and if you enjoy doing something, you are more likely to keep wanting to do it.

Is this a hard joke- There was a bug in production. So, our team fixed it before we logged off. The lead checked and informed that it was working. So, I said, "Weekend is saved". Is it offensive ?

@pc_fuel That's not a joke, just a comment on what happened. Your weekend was just saved.  A joke would have been "There goes my weekend plans.  Looks like there is still time to add more bugs ;)"

@Questor - you can join my scrums anytime

@pc_fuel - hell no! A joke would have been: "awesome to hear it is working again, I've reminded the team that they are only to run jobsecurity.exe before contract renewal time"

"Why Microsoft Teams is an abomination"  This isn't banter, nor is it a joke /s

It depends on the client, on your own corporate culture, on the occasion, and on the jokes.
I've worked in environments where any communication that wasn't strictly business related was severely frowned upon. In such an environment any joke would be a big no-no.
I've never been directly employed by companies that had such a culture, but I've worked as a contractor in such companies, and obviously as a contractor you're expected to adapt to your customer's culture (which at times can create clashes with your own corporate culture, in which case be cautious).
And quite obviously any potentially offensive or disrespectful "joke" is a big no-no. So nothing political, religious, sexual, or related to health conditions, and that's just a start. Be very very careful. And remember, just because the customer does something doesn't mean it's ok for you to do it as a representative of your employer! And that goes beyond jokes. If your customer's rep drinks himself into a stupor at a business dinner, don't follow suit!

Everyone is different and I cannot tell you what your client likes. I can tell you how we do it.
The Daily Scrum starts at 09:30, has only work related stuff and is called to end as soon as that is over.
Anyone who wants to have some jokes, banter or just talk about non-work smalltalk before getting into it will join the channel early. If you arrive at 09:20 to joke around with colleagues, that is fine. Everyone that is already there is obviously up for it.
At 09:30 the Scrum Master will start the meeting and that's it. Back to business. People who cannot, will not or don't have time today for a "coffee machine talk" will join at 09:29 and be happy.
If you can communicate that, so everyone knows, it should be the ideal solution, where everyone can pick their own preferences for this every day.
